# Export salesforce to postgresql?

Tags: data-export

is there an option to export salesforce data into postgresql (in my local machine)?
Is there an opensource one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't see a problem with recreating your schema in database and then  use data loader to export data from Salesforce to csv file. Lift constraints in Postgresql and then use (example)

```
COPY contacts(first_name,last_name, email) 
FROM 'C:\tmp\contacts.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

Its time consuming and partially manual task but easly doable.

And here is open source version: https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader

Comment: how do I extract Sales force data into csv?

Comment: As I said. Using data loader. I even provided you a link for open source version. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm
Here is full guide.
DataLoader is a tool created by Salesforce to export/import large sets of salesforce data

Answer (score 0):

One can import Salesforce data into windsor.ai and export it into PostgreSQL: https://windsor.ai/connectors/salesforce/ The team has just implemented custom Salesforce objects and fields export for their client.

You may try it for free, but exporting substantial amount of data requires signing to some plan: https://windsor.ai/pricing/ You may also request a quote.

Disclaimer: I do work for the company but not in the team that integrates Salesforce.